# How to secure a Google Cloud Task in Java

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, google-cloud-tasks

Is there a way to secure Google Cloud Tasks so that they only run if they are initiated by your Google App Engine in Java?

With the [old legacy Push Tasks](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/legacy/standard/java/taskqueue/push/creating-handlers#reading_request_headers) you could set up a security-constraint in your web.xml but this doesn't work for me anyone.

What is the recommended way to secure a Google Cloud Task and know it came from your application?

Perhaps setting a handler in the [app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/reference/app-yaml?tab=java#handlers_element) file to secure those Task urls is an option? I don't see a good example of how to do that though.

Comment: When you say 'only run if from your application'. Would that be the same as using an OIDC token on the task and securing the target so that only that service account can call it?

Comment: @rossco Not sure what you mean but take a look at the link to the old legacy push tasks way of securing your tasks. I want to do what they describe there - that is, Cloud Tasks will only successfully authenticate and run if it is my Google App Application that calls them. Maybe App Engine passes in some sort of header? For example. cron jobs pass an app-engine header: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml#securing_urls_for_cron - I don't see any such headers for Cloud Tasks

Comment: When you create the Cloud Task you can specify an oidc_token field which includes the service account that will execute the task (e.g. call Cloud Functions, Cloud Run etc). You grant that service account the appropriate permission (e.g. Cloud Run invoker). I've never used the legacy tasks but that looks like it would have the same result https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/samples/cloud-tasks-create-http-task-with-token

Comment: @rossco That link looks like it would work. But how do you then check that authentication in the actual task servlet handler? Here is an example of a handler: https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/creating-appengine-handlers

Comment: You don't need to check anything. Cloud Tasks adds an Authorisation Bearer token and fires it at the target URL. If it has the permissions to call the target, all good. If it does not you will see a 403 error in the logs

Comment: @rossco But will Cloud Tasks reject any request that does not have that auth? Because from my tests, I can just send an empty curl request to my task handler url and it executes.

Comment: No Cloud Tasks won't reject the addition of new tasks. Any person or service account that has the IAM permission cloudtasks.tasks.create can do that. But you would be carefull who you grant that to